# Генерация Json всех полей таблицы

Tags: sql, sqlite

Есть [много](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jeach) функций, что-бы сгенерировать `json`. Но как сгенерировать всю таблицу целиком не указывая имя каждого поля и значения через `json_object(label1,value1,...)`?

Comment: Увы-увы... по-моему, вообще ни одна DBMS не имеет средств для одновременной манипуляции и данными, и метаданными (даже если имеется TABLE statement или нечто аналогичное). Ну если не считать отдельных подзапросов в схему. Или неких расширений (но навскидку - не припоминаю таких). Так что самое разумное - строить соотв. запрос с использованием динамического SQL на основании запроса в INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

Comment: Я второй день с `sql` я так не умею  Придётя ручками 